# excel question - how to do a formula for % variance

Tags: excel, formula

I know how to use if statements in excel, but im wondering how to do % variance using if.

e.g.

two numbers

- A1 = 100
- A2 = 99

I am trying to find out whether the 2nd number is within 2% of the first (which is true in this example)

Any maths geniuses know where to start with this?

Cheers

ke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight forward way (using simple math only and not excel percentage functions):

```
=IF(AND(A2>(A1-(A1*2/100)),A2<(A1+(A1*2/100))),"yes","no")
```

You can switch the >,< with >=,<= respectively if exactly 2% away is also good...

Answer (score 0):

Asking if `A2` is within 2% of `A1` is the same as asking if `A2 / A1` lies within the range `0.98` to `1.02`:

```
IF( AND( 0.98 <= (A2 / A1), (A2 / A1) <= 1.02 ), <true>, <false> )
```

Note I have used 'number line order' here to make it easier to see that we are looking for `A2 / A1` to lie *between* the two outer numbers.